# SQL Server select distinct some columns but show all

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database that updates weekly, there is often repeat information but the `datetime` column is always different. How do I display all columns including the timestamp but only display unique rows not including the timestamp?

I need to keep the information for a month so I am unable to delete the repeat rows. Showing the most recent timestamp row would be ideal, but that does not matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, MAX(TimeColumn) FROM MyTable GROUP BY ColumnA, ColumnB` would group all rows where `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` are identical, using `MAX()` to select the most recent `TimeColumn` for each.

Comment: Please, **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46413455/edit)** your question, add table structure, sample data, and desired outputs to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c...., max(timestamp)
FROM table
GROUP BY col_a, col_b, col_c... -- Same cols as above except timestamp
```